# Вопрос по флексбоксам

Tags: html, css

У меня есть контейнер и 8 элементов. Как мне при помощи флексбоксов растянуть это на две строчки, в каждой по 4 элемента. Ширина элементов должна составлять 20%.

**Примечание:** Без создания дополнительных контейнеров.

https://jsfiddle.net/qbf0xm37/

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100vw;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
.block{
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
.block{
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: calc(20%/3);
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.block:nth-child(4n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```